# Semantic similarity of strings - poor results

Tags: python, nlp, semantics, similarity

My goal is to create a basic program which semantically compares strings and decides which is more similar (in terms of semantics) to which. For now I did not want to built from scratch a new (doc2vec?) model in `NTLK` or in `SKlearn` or in `Gensim` but I wanted to test the already existing APIs which can do semantic analysis.

Specifically, I chose to test `ParallelDots AI API` and for this reason I wrote the following program in python:

```
import  paralleldots

api_key = "*******************************************"

paralleldots.set_api_key(api_key)

phrase1 = "I have a swelling on my eyelid"
phrase2 = "I have a lump on my hand"
phrase3 = "I have a lump on my lid"

print(phrase1, " VS ", phrase3, "\n")
print(paralleldots.similarity(phrase1, phrase3), "\n\n")

print(phrase2, " VS ", phrase3, "\n")
print(paralleldots.similarity(phrase2, phrase3))
```

This is the response I get from the API:

```
I have a swelling on my eyelid  VS  I have a lump on my lid 

{'normalized_score': 1.38954, 'usage': 'By accessing ParallelDots API or using information generated by ParallelDots API, you are agreeing to be bound by the ParallelDots API Terms of Use: http://www.paralleldots.com/terms-and-conditions', 'actual_score': 0.114657, 'code': 200} 


I have a lump on my hand  VS  I have a lump on my lid 

{'normalized_score': 3.183968, 'usage': 'By accessing ParallelDots API or using information generated by ParallelDots API, you are agreeing to be bound by the ParallelDots API Terms of Use: http://www.paralleldots.com/terms-and-conditions', 'actual_score': 0.323857, 'code': 200}
```

This response is rather disappointing for me. It is obvious that the phrase

> I have a lump on my lid

is almost semantically identical to the phrase

> I have a swelling on my eyelid

and it is also related to the phrase

> I have a lump on my hand

as they are referring to lumps but obviously it is not at all as close as to the former one. However, `ParallelDots AI API` outputs almost the exact opposite results.

If I am right, `ParallelDots AI API` is one of most popular APIs for semantic analysis along with others such as `Dandelion API` etc but it fetches so disappointing results. I expected that these APIs were using some rich databases of synonyms. I have also tested `Dandelion API` with these three phrases but the results are poor too (and actually they are even worse).

What can I fix at my program above to retrieve more reasonable results?

Is there any other faster way to semantically compare strings?

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the data scientists at ParallelDots. While it is unfortunate that you did not get the desired results, please be aware that general models available via an API are trained on publically available datasets like news and twitter.

In the case of semantic similarity API, we have trained it on news corpus, and it is highly unlikely that the relatedness of lump and swelling can be picked up if one reads general news articles.

Just the word lump has so many different meanings in English under different context that it makes the model highly data dependent. For example, in the financial world lump is closer to sum, investments, etc.

If you are trying to find semantic relatedness on your domain data, I would advise you to utilize ParallelDots Enterprise services to customize the semantic relatedness model on your data. You need a large corpus of unlabelled data to do the customization, and you benefit from higher accuracy which only improves as more data gets iteratively added to the model.

I will end the answer with a general note which I have observed with software developers when they tend to services like AI which are probabilistic in nature. As a software engineer, we are trained to do troubleshooting when results are not what we expect for a set of inputs, however in machine learning; we tend to test a model on sufficiently large samples before trying to debug it and reach a conclusion. I will encourage the software developers to build a test set and run the AI models on it to find the accuracy metrics and evaluate whether the model is useful for their dataset.

Comment: Thank you for your response @ankits. Yes, I had in my mind that the general API would be probably trained on general texts from newspapers etc which probably do not contain so many medical terms ("lump, "swelling"). However, in my specific example, the API could solve the problem simply by firstly calling a synonyms API instead of only (probably) depending on word2vec models etc.

Comment: But for sure your advices are very useful. However, frequently we are short of time and we are searching for the right API which at least do not miss simple cases (like in my example) even though it may not handle so well more complicated ones. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: I get your point @Poete_Maudit and trust me, we are launching a 2.0 version of our semantic API including an easy to use library for training on your dataset too!